# ADFS 403 Error On login page

Tags: adfs, http-status-code-403

I just installed ADFS on my Windows Server 2012 and I am getting stuck.
If I go to https://mail.mywebsi.te/adfs/ls I instantly get an 403 error without it actually showing the Default login screen.

With kind of regards,

EnderWolf

Comment: I still doesn't work any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a supported endpoint in itself. Normally, that is followed by either WS-Fed or SAML parameters.

To test you could try the metadata endpoint:

https://server.domain.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

or IDP Initiated:

https://server.domain.com/adfs/ls/IdPInitiatedSignOn.aspx

Comment: Looking in the Event Viewer I found this message: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12751048/ I think this might be related to the 403.

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753197/cannot-connect-to-the-configuration-database ?

Comment: I have but it doesn't fix anything; There is no SQL server  service and I only have one site collection an I have checked the permissions.